# Duplicate service in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose there are two third party Angular modules Mod1.js and Mod2.js  Each of them exposes service named ExpService 
Suppose that one client module named ClientMod1.js needs to use ExpService from Mod1.js and second module ClientMod2.js needs ExpService from Mod2.js 
How AngularJs resolves ambiguity if exist ? How correctly Mod1 and Mod2 should be used ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way you can do that is to create get your own instance of the injector. When the modules are combined, the last service will win - i.e. if you have two services named "service" then the last registration is the instance you'll get. Let's assume you have two modules that define the same service (but it is implemented differently):

```
var mod1 = angular.module("mod1", []);
mod1.service("service", function() {
    this.echo = function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    };
});
var mod2 = angular.module("mod2", []);
mod2.service("service", function() {
    this.say = function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    };
});
```

Now I want to use it like this:

```
var client1 = angular.module("client1", ["mod1"]);
client1.controller("controller1", function($scope, service) {
    $scope.text = "client1";
    service.echo("client1");
});
var client2 = angular.module("client2", ["mod2"]); 
client2.controller("controller2", function($scope, service) {
    $scope.text = "client2";
    service.say("client2");
});
```

Seems logical. However, when I register the modules together to make an "app" like this:

```
angular.module("myApp", ["client1", "client2"]);
```

What happens is mod2 overwrites the service from mod1, so the call in client1 fails. To fix this, I change client1 to get the injector for mod1 and it works:

```
client1.controller("controller1", function($scope) {
    $scope.text = "client1";
    var service = angular.injector(["mod1"]).get("service");
    service.echo("client1");
});
```

Now I can reference the service even though it has the same name. Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/xEt94/